# Why does Chrome Devtools's zoom cut off the right side of my page sometimes, and other times it doesn't?

Tags: google-chrome, frontend, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

This is driving me bananas. I am working on a webpage and the zoom in Devtools sometimes cuts a portion of my page off, and other times, it doesn't. Often, I can correct this problem by clicking the Toggle Device Toolbar button (circled in red). But other times, it does nothing.

As you can see in my screenshot, I want to view my page at 1440 x 800. But Devtools is only showing me 1377.43px x 765.24px (circled in green). There is plenty of room for it to show me the full width. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?
[screenshot of devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpeFi.png)